# How to send the video signal from an android device to a client via websocket, WebRTC or RTSP?

Tags: android, websocket, webrtc, rtsp, android-camera2

I am going to start developing an app on android to send the video from the camera to a client and that this client can send commands to interact with the camera, turn on the flash, zoom, set the iso level, etc., my main problem is to send the video signal to the client and what technology to use: websocket, WebRTC, RTSP, etc.
Any idea, the truth is that of any of the options I find very little information on how to send the video signal.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If your android device and clients is in a LAN, I think SOCKET is enghou. Otherwise, if the android device has a confirm IP, and then you can use Jetty or NanoHttpd to run a webserver on the device, and then client can get vedio signal and send commands to the device through RESFUL interfaces of the webserver.